# Uncaught ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'amtSavingsInput' before initialization

Tags: javascript

I have three forms which do some calculations and then chart them. Everything worked for form 1/chart 1 and form2/chart2 but when I coded form3/chart3/ in the same way it broke. The steps are the same and its only the calculation thats different. I have tried many different ways like only loading after the DOM is loaded to get it working but to no avail.

The error I get is "Uncaught ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'amtSavingsInput' before initialization"

This is the code for form3/chart3:

```
// Get the input fields and chart canvas
let amtSavingsInput = document.getElementById('amt_Savings');
let yieldSavingsInput = document.getElementById('yield_Savings');
let amtVanguardInput = document.getElementById('amt_Vanguard');
let yieldVanguardInput = document.getElementById('yield_Vanguard');

// Get the cashInChart canvas element
const moneyMapChartElement = document.getElementById('moneyMapChart');

// Set the initial data for the chart
const chart3 = {
  labels: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: '',
      data: [],
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.6)',
      borderWidth: 1
    }
  ]
};

// Create the chart
const moneyMapChart = new Chart(moneyMapChartElement, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: chart3,
  options: {
    responsive: false,
    scales: {
      y: {
        type: 'linear', // Set the scale type to 'linear'
        beginAtZero: true
      }
    }
  }
});

// Function to calculate and update the chart
function updateChart() {
  let amtSavings = parseFloat(amtSavingsInput.value);
  let yieldSavings = parseFloat(yieldSavingsInput.value);
  let amtVanguard = parseFloat(amtVanguardInput.value);
  let yieldVanguard = parseFloat(yieldVanguardInput.value);

  // Convert monthly savings to yearly savings
  amtSavings *= 12;
  amtVanguard *= 12;

  const years = 5; // Set the desired number of years

  const capitals = calculateCapitalGrowth(amtSavings, yieldSavings, amtVanguard, yieldVanguard, years);

  // Update the chart data
  moneyMapChart.data.datasets[0].data = capitals;
  moneyMapChart.update();
}

// Add event listeners to input fields
amtSavingsInput.addEventListener('input', updateChart);
yieldSavingsInput.addEventListener('input', updateChart);
amtVanguardInput.addEventListener('input', updateChart);
yieldVanguardInput.addEventListener('input', updateChart);
```

with a basic html bootstrap form:

```
  <div class="col-md-6">
                <h2>Savings and Investments</h2>
                <p>Growing wealth is about holding onto money. Choose how much of your £<span class="inline-block"
                        id="cashLeftDisplay2"></span> (cash leftover) that you will save or invest.</p>
                <form> <!-- Savings & Investments form-->
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="amt_Savings" class="form-label">Amount in a Savings Account</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="amt_Savings" value="0" placeholder="0">
                      </div>
                      <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="yield_Savings" class="form-label">Yearly Interest % Earned</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="yield_Savings" value="0" placeholder="0">
                      </div>
                      <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="amt_Vanguard" class="form-label">Amount in Vanguard Account</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="amt_Vanguard" value="0" placeholder="0">
                      </div>
                      <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="yield_Vanguard" class="form-label">Benchmark % Return</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="yield_Vanguard" value="0" placeholder="0">
                      </div> 
                </form>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" id="nextButton">Next</button>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't find any issue with your code, it's just missing the canvas element. It runs with no errors in here

```js
let amtSavingsInput = document.getElementById('amt_Savings');
let yieldSavingsInput = document.getElementById('yield_Savings');
let amtVanguardInput = document.getElementById('amt_Vanguard');
let yieldVanguardInput = document.getElementById('yield_Vanguard');

// Get the cashInChart canvas element
const moneyMapChartElement = document.getElementById('moneyMapChart');

// Set the initial data for the chart
const chart3 = {
  labels: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: '',
      data: [],
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.6)',
      borderWidth: 1
    }
  ]
};

// Create the chart
const moneyMapChart = new Chart(moneyMapChartElement, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: chart3,
  options: {
    responsive: false,
    scales: {
      y: {
        type: 'linear', // Set the scale type to 'linear'
        beginAtZero: true
      }
    }
  }
});

// Function to calculate and update the chart
function updateChart() {
  let amtSavings = parseFloat(amtSavingsInput.value);
  let yieldSavings = parseFloat(yieldSavingsInput.value);
  let amtVanguard = parseFloat(amtVanguardInput.value);
  let yieldVanguard = parseFloat(yieldVanguardInput.value);

  // Convert monthly savings to yearly savings
  amtSavings *= 12;
  amtVanguard *= 12;

  const years = 5; // Set the desired number of years

  const capitals = calculateCapitalGrowth(amtSavings, yieldSavings, amtVanguard, yieldVanguard, years);

  // Update the chart data
  moneyMapChart.data.datasets[0].data = capitals;
  moneyMapChart.update();
}

// Add event listeners to input fields
amtSavingsInput.addEventListener('input', updateChart);
yieldSavingsInput.addEventListener('input', updateChart);
amtVanguardInput.addEventListener('input', updateChart);
yieldVanguardInput.addEventListener('input', updateChart);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
 <div class="col-md-6">
                <h2>Savings and Investments</h2>
                <p>Growing wealth is about holding onto money. Choose how much of your £<span class="inline-block"
                        id="cashLeftDisplay2"></span> (cash leftover) that you will save or invest.</p>
                <form> <!-- Savings & Investments form-->
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="amt_Savings" class="form-label">Amount in a Savings Account</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="amt_Savings" value="0" placeholder="0">
                      </div>
                      <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="yield_Savings" class="form-label">Yearly Interest % Earned</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="yield_Savings" value="0" placeholder="0">
                      </div>
                      <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="amt_Vanguard" class="form-label">Amount in Vanguard Account</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="amt_Vanguard" value="0" placeholder="0">
                      </div>
                      <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="yield_Vanguard" class="form-label">Benchmark % Return</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="yield_Vanguard" value="0" placeholder="0">
                      </div> 
                </form>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" id="nextButton">Next</button>
            </div>
<canvas id=moneyMapChart></canvas> <!-- <== Added! -->
```